# Regular expression doesn't work in grep

Tags: regex, macos, grep

Why grep doesn't match "COL1,COL2,COL3," with this regexp as expected but "COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,"? It matches correctly in text editor but not using grep, am I missing any special escaping or..? (using OS X Lion)

The text:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9
```

The command:

```
grep -E --color=auto '^([^,]*,){3}' file.csv
```

Grep version:
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command:

```
grep -E --color=auto '^([^,]*,){3}' file.csv
```

will only color the string `COL1,COL2,COL3,` differently but if you want that string in output then use `-o` option like this:

```
grep -E -o '^([^,]*,){3}'
```

Comment: Hi, i wasn't probably clear enough. The problem is that it doesn't match COL1,COL2,COL3, as expected but COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,...whereas e.g. in sublime editor the regexp matches correctly COL1,COL2,COL3,

Comment: I think your grep version is culprit. I have `GNU grep 2.6.3` and it matches and highlights `COL1,COL2,COL3,` correctly

Comment: Really, looks like bug in that version, I've tried other greps and it works as expected...